# Server Sent Events not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, tomcat, jersey

i am developing a web application with angular 4 and java. I am using server sent events to send some text data to the frontend. In the backend i am using jersey and this is my backend code

```
eventOutput.write(new OutboundEvent.Builder()
       .id(decodedToken)
       .name("responseBody")
       .data(String.class, respBody.toString()).build());
```

Frontend i am using angular 4 and the code looks like

```
var evtSource = new EventSource("url");
 source.addEventListener('eventName', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Everything works fine in Mozilla firefox. When i use chrome with tomcat and windows everything works fine. But with tomcat+linux and chrome, i see the error in the console.as

> EventSource's response has a charset ("iso-8859-1") that is not UTF-8.
>   Aborting the connection.

What could be the issue. What is the fix? Please help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat supports charset : iso-8859-1 by default. Please try

```
@Produces("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
eventOutput.write(new OutboundEvent.Builder()
       .id(decodedToken)
       .name("responseBody")
       .data(String.class, respBody.toString()).build());
```

Answer (score 4):

If the issue is with tomcat in linux, you can update bin\startup.sh the following line

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"
```

See [Force tomcat to use UTF-8 in linux](https://support.filecatalyst.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/370/9/forcing-tomcat-to-use-utf-8-character-set-in-linux) tutorial

Comment: But wouldnt this be applied to all the requests? Can we do anything only for eventstreams ?

Comment: Try adding to builder `.mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);` or `.mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE+ ";charset=utf-8");`

Comment: The builder takes only one MediaType parameter, whereas the above snippet suggests to use String type. Moreover SSE should be sent as text/event-stream, so the ideal MediaType should be MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS isnt it? And then a possibility to override the charset?

Comment: I know you can concatenate ";charset=UTF-8" to relevant media type

Comment: Okay ...i am gonna try this.. .mediaType(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE.withCharset("UTF-8"))

Comment: The entire stream is text/event-stream, but each event has it's own mediatype (which could be text/plain, for simplifying testing)